# Use require/new to instantiate a new object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, require

I have very simple beginner problem using node.js but I cannot seem to get it to work correctly.

All I want is to be able to create objects using the 'new' operator in the index.js file.
For demonstration purposes, I have created a simple `Person` object inside a Person.js file (which lies in the same directory as my index.js) like this:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this._name = 'bob';
  }

  set name(name) {
    this._name = name
  }

  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }  
}
```

Now I want to do something like this (in the index.js file):

```
var p = require('./Person.js')
var bob = new p.Person()
```

The error message I get is telling me that Person is not a constructor:

```
var bob = new p.Person()
      ^

TypeError: p.Person is not a constructor
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/.../index.js:59:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can only import something if you exported it already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to require or import class/function/object/anything from another JS file, you need to export that and import/require that in your current file. These are called modules.

In your case, You need to export the `Person` class after creating. Otherwise JS doesn't have any reference to it. Add

```
module.exports = Person
```

below the `Person` class. Now you can instantiate by

```
const Person = require('./person');
const p = new Person();
```

For the new ES6 classes you can use `import/export` as well.

```
// Export Person Class

export default class Person {
    ....
}

// Now, import
import Person from './person'
```

Comment: I tried using exports before as well, but I think I got confused about the many ways things can be done in JS... Your solution works for me, thank you very much. :)